# test objects created inside a method jmockit

Tags: jmockit

The method which I wanted to test looks like:

```
public void method1(String str) {
     ParmaObjectRequest request = new ParmaObjectRequest(str);
     this.instanceVar.save(request);
}
```

I wanted to test if `this.instanceVar.save` is called with an ParmaObjectRequest object with str value using jmockit.
The test case I have written looks like below and I am able to test that my method is called 1 times but not the parameter inside it.

```
    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        new Expectations() {
            {
                this.instanceVar.save((ParmaObjectRequest) any);
                times = 1;
            }
        };
        testObject.method1("dummyString");
    }
```

But I also wanted to test that `this.instanceVar.save` is called with object containing `"dummyString"`.

Answer (score 0):

In the Expectations block, change "this.instanceVar" to "testObject.instanceVar"